# Kylin - Group by Rollup and Cube

Tags: kylin, apache-calcite

I am trying to use the ROLLUP and CUBE operators to summarise data using the sample cube. If I execute the query the following error message is returned:

> Internal error: Error while applying rule OLAPAggregateRule, args [rel#1246:LogicalAggregate.NONE.[](input=rel#1245:Subset#1.NONE.[],group={0, 1},groups=[{0, 1}, {0}, {}],indicator=true,SUMOFPRICE=SUM($2))].

I am using the documentation from http://calcite.apache.org/docs/reference.html to build the query.

Test queries:

**Simple query not using a cube**

select a, b, sum(c)
from (values (1, 2, 3, 4)) as t(a, b, c, d)
group by rollup(a, b)

This query returns the expected results

**Query using KYLIN_SALES table using ROLLUP operator**

select seller_id, leaf_categ_id, sum(price) as SumOfPrice
from kylin_sales
group by rollup(seller_id, leaf_categ_id)

The error mentioned at the start of question is returned when executing this query.

The Kylin logs show the following when the error occurs:
[image: Kylin logs]

Answer (score 0):

I see you [asked the same question on the Kylin dev list](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kylin-dev/201609.mbox/%3CCAE6Ew1oCWxNmtVxehthPx5JTunkvA33gkMoSzBWb5neUDct55A%40mail.gmail.com%3E). Since it's probably a bug, you'll get your answer there.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'll follow the dev list response.

Answer (score 0):

From the Kylin development mailing list: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kylin-dev/201609.mbox/browser

> KYLIN-1732 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KYLIN-1732 is what you
>   want and it is to be release in v1.5.4 soon. Please try again on the coming
>   v1.5.4.